# Python Requests module not refreshing new page contents

Tags: python, pagination, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

Hi i want to crawl XHR request url which has JSON feed but when i change query paramater page value to 2 or any other it retrieve data from page 1 but when i did the same in browser it shows data according to its page.
enter code here

```
import json
import requests
url = 'https://www.daraz.pk/computer-graphic-cards/?'
params_dict = {}
params_dict['ajax']= 'true'
params_dict['page']= 1
params_dict['spm'] = 'a2a0e.home.cate_2_9.1.35e349378NoL6f' 
res = requests.get(url, params=params_dict)
data = json.loads(res.text)
res.url # url changes but content is same of page 1

info = data.get('mods').get('listItems')
for i in info:
   print(i['name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think how the data is being returned has issues. I modified the call slightly by looping over the pages.

Looking at the data returned, it seems that some products are being returned on multiple pages even in the UI.

```
for page_num in range(1, 7):
    res = requests.get('https://www.daraz.pk/computer-graphic-cards/?ajax=true&page=' + str(page_num)).json()
    info = res.get('mods').get('listItems')
    for i in info:
       print('%s:%s:%s---------%s' % (i['itemId'],i['sellerName'],i['skuId'],i['name']))
    print('----------------------- PAGE %s ------------------------------------------' % (page_num))
```

Data returned from this code snippet is linked [here](https://pastebin.com/vbxx6bLZ).

Comment: I appreciate your help but i tried looping over pages and got same result as yours each page shows same items from page 1 like in your pastebin code snippet